# On the Averaging Operator

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

In the standard Lebesgue space $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, given $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and a disjoint sequence $\{E_{j,N}\}_{j}$ measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with finite measure $0<|E_{j,N}|<1/N$ and  $\bigcup_{j}E_{j,N}=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, define the averaging operator
\begin{align*}
A_{N}(f)=\sum_{j}\left(\dfrac{1}{|E_{j,N}|}\int_{E_{j,N}}f(x)dx\right)\chi_{E_{j,N}},
\end{align*}
is it necessary that $A_{N}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

I have searched MSE it seems to me that if each $E_{j,N}$ is of a dyadic cube, then a theorem of martingale theory says that the averaging operator converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.

I googled the issue of this kind of averaging operator, not much to say about it. I am looking for any reference to this issue if possible.

Comment: Stein E. Singular integrals uses that *averaging operator* in the discussion of the Calderón-Zygmund decomposition. Many other books on Classical Fourier analysis will have a presentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I know is "Alt - linear functional analysis" 7.21. Theory about projection operators gives lots of nice results about this, including $L^p$-convergence.

(I can not say if 7.21 is the correct number as I am using the german book. But the section is called "piecewise constant approximation".)

Comment: Thank you, but as I look at it, the book concerns about the interval instead of arbitrary measurable set.

Comment: I do not expect a lot to change...

Comment: Thank you anyway, it still helps.

Comment: No problem, hope you'll figure it out